# After a few hours all requests start to fail with an UnknownHostException

Tags: android, httpconnection, intentservice, android-networking, android-internet

I'm using an `IntentService` that receives an intent from an `AlarmManager` every 30 seconds and updates my app widgets. Every time it runs, it brings data from a server using a `DefaultHttpClient`.

Everything works fine for a few hours, but after a few hours the request stops working and always returns an `UnknownHostException`. This happens consistently **every time** I leave the device on for half a day.

Restarting the device solves the problem, so it's not a server issue.

I'll be very grateful for any help, because I've been struggling with this issue for a few days already!